# Number of points where gravitational field due to $N$ point-masses vanishes

Tags: newtonian-gravity, mathematical-physics, potential

Given $N$ distinct fixed points of equal mass in the plane (eventually, in space), let $f(N)$ denote the number of points $P$ for which the gravitational field at $P$ vanishes.

For example $f(2)=1$ and for $3$ collinear points, $f(3)=3$.

I conjecture that $f(N)$ is finite and nonzero.

Is this true?

Comment: Suggestion to question (v2): Generalize to not necessarily equal masses.

Comment: Related post in 2D: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16386/2451

Comment: Crossposted to [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2457458/points-where-the-gravitational-field-of-n-masses-vanishes#comment5085342_2457458) and [MO.se](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282770/conjecture-finitely-many-points-where-gravitational-field-due-to-n-masses-vanis).

Comment: Duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148962/ With a détaillés answer at that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there always an equilibrium point in space for gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148962/)