# Points where electric field is zero when charges are present at vertices of a regular polygon

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, equilibrium

There is a $n$-sided regular polygon with a charge $q$ at each vertex. I know that there are $n$ points, other the center of the polygon, where the electric field is zero. But why is this so? Is there a general way to prove it?

PS: I know some questions related to my question have been asked, but none of them gives me a satisfactory reason why there should be a total of $n+1$ neutral points in space for such a charge distribution.

Comment: Related (you probably already found this, but it might help future readers):  [Electric Field inside a regular polygon with corner charges](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108929/)

Comment: Also, Griffiths has the calculation of the "off-center" null points as Exercise 2.58 in the fourth edition.  He says that "there are $n$ points in addition to the center" in general, and cites two works:  [Baker, *Am. J. Phys.* **52**, p. 265 (1984)](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.13703);  and [Kiang & Tindall, *Am. J. Phys.* **53**, p. 593 (1985)](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.14395).  I don't have access to them just now but I'll put in an ILL request and report back once I have a chance to read them.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert , I've seen them, but they don't provide a rigorous proof that there are $n$ off center points where field is zero. Not only this, Griffiths assumes that the null points are on symmetry axis of some sort, it would be true if and only if there are $n$ off-center null points, but a nice proof of this eludes me.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a line connecting two adjacent charges on your polygon, and then another line which bisects that one, going in the positive x direction through the center of the polygon (at x = 0). To show that your premise is true, you would need to find one (and only one, if (n) is odd) other point (other than at x = 0) on that line of symmetry, where the sum of the x components of the fields is zero. For a general proof, the distances and components of distances would be a function of (n), and would depend on whether (n) was odd or even.

Comment: it shows that there are at least $n$ such points, other than the center, but it doesn't show that there are no more. That's what I want to know a proof of.

Answer (score 2):

1. For what it's worth, 2D [Morse theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory) (with the assumption that all critical points for the electric potential are non-degenerate) yields that
   $$c_1-c_0~=~n-1\qquad\text{and}\qquad c_2~=~0,$$
   where
   $$\begin{align} c_0~:=~& \#{\rm minimum~pts}, \cr 
   c_1~:=~& \#{\rm saddle~pts},  \cr 
   c_2~:=~& \#{\rm maximum~pts},\end{align}$$
   cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/16529/2451).
2. So under these assumptions$^1$ OP's claim for the regular $n$-polygon$^2$
   $$\begin{align}V(z)~=~&\sum_{j=1}^n \left|z-\exp\frac{2\pi i j}{n}\right|^{-1}\cr
   ~=~&\sum_{j=1}^n \left(\left(x-\cos\frac{2\pi  j}{n}\right)^2+\left(y-\sin\frac{2\pi  j}{n}\right)^2\right)^{-1/2}\cr
   ~=~&\sum_{j=1}^n\left(1+r^2-2r\cos\left(\theta-\frac{2\pi j}{n}\right)\right)^{-1/2}
   \end{align} $$
   that the number of critical points are $c_2+c_1+c_0=n+1$ would follow if we can show that $c_0=1$, i.e. that the center is the only local minimum.

---

$^1$ It is not difficult to see that the center $r=0$ is a non-degenerate critical point:

$$ V(r,\theta)~=~\left\{ 
\begin{array}{rl}
n\left(1+\frac{r^2}{4}\right) +{\cal O}(r^3) &\text{minimum pt for } n\geq 3,\cr 2+\frac{r^2}{2}\left(1+3\cos 2\theta\right)+{\cal O}(r^3)&\text{saddle pt for } n=2. \end{array}\right. $$

$^2$ We assume that $n\geq 3$. If $n=1$, then $c_0=0=c_1$. If $n=2$, then $c_0=0$ and $c_1=1$.

Comment: This assumes that the potential has no degenerate critical points, which may well be true but I can't see an obvious argument for it.

Comment: Also, I assume you're using the electric potential as your Morse function, but you don't say that explicitly in your answer.

Comment: Good points. I updated the answer.

Comment: Could this be proven by instead looking at the potential in $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{ n \text{ points}\}$?  It would still be the case that all critical points must lie in the plane of the charges (idea: $\partial \phi/\partial z \neq 0$ has the same sign as $z$ for $z \neq 0$ for any one positive charge, and therefore for a collection of positive charges).  And in this case, we have $c_0 = c_3 = 0$ automatically by the "no local extrema" property of the electric potential, which gives us an additional lever. So the goal would be to show that $c_1 + c_2 = n+1$. ...

Comment: ... But there may be an impediment to this that I'm not seeing because I barely know how Morse theory works in 2D, let alone 3D.

Comment: Notes for later: 1. The critical pts must in any case all lie within the $n$-polygon to obey force equilibrium. 2. $V(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{r}V(\frac{1}{r},\theta)$.